# NSTextFieldCell draws white background only when not the first responder

Tags: nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I have two `NSTextField`s in a storyboard, both remain untouched from the default configuration, except I have changed their classes to a subclass. I've also subclassed the inner `NSTextFieldCell`. I've customized each as desired - pretty simple subclasses. The text field that is the first responder appears as expected, but the other text field does not. It is drawing a white background for its cell. Toggling between the two fields toggles the background. How can I remove this white background from the cell?

`LoginTextField`:

```
- (void)baseInit {
    self.drawsBackground = NO;
    self.wantsLayer = YES;
    self.backgroundColor = [[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];
    self.textColor = [NSColor blackColor];

    CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    layer.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor.CGColor;
    layer.borderWidth = 0;
    layer.cornerRadius = 6;

    self.layer = layer;
}
```

`LoginTextFieldCell`:

```
- (void)baseInit {
    self.drawsBackground = NO;
    self.focusRingType = NSFocusRingTypeNone;
}
```

[image]

If I override this function, the white background disappears, but so does the placeholder and text labels when not the first responder.

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    return [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

[image]

I'm developing the app in Xcode 7, running on OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who also saw this problem, the solution that worked for me was to set `bordered` to `NO` and configure `self.layer` instead of creating a new `CALayer`.

`LoginTextField`:

```
- (void)baseInit {
    self.drawsBackground = NO;
    self.wantsLayer = YES;
    self.textColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    self.bordered = NO;

    self.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
}
```